# UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout bug on iOS 14.3

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout

I'm experiencing a weird layout issue on **iOS 14.3** with collection views using a `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout` combined in my case with the `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource`.
The issue is about the wrong position of the inner `_UICollectionViewOrthogonalScrollerEmbeddedScrollView` when you have an orthogonal section preceded by an intrinsic height section.

Fortunately I'm able to reproduce the issue very easily.
Consider having this data source:

```swift
private var dataSource: UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, String>!

enum Section: Int, Hashable, CaseIterable {
    case first = 0
    case second = 1
}
```

For each section you create the following layout:

```swift
private extension Section {
    var section: NSCollectionLayoutSection {
        switch self {
        case .first:
            let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .estimated(50))
            let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
            let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .estimated(50))
            let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])
            let section: NSCollectionLayoutSection = .init(group: group)
            return section
        case .second:
            let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1))
            let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
            let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .absolute(200), heightDimension: .absolute(200))
            let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])
            let section: NSCollectionLayoutSection = .init(group: group)
            section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .continuous
            section.contentInsets = .init(top: 10, leading: 10, bottom: 10, trailing: 10)
            section.interGroupSpacing = 10
            return section
        }
    }
}
```

The thing breaking the layout is having into the `.first` section both `itemSize` and `groupSize` with `.estimated` height.

You can see the result below on **iOS 14.3**: at the first glance the layout is visually correct, but you immediately realize the fact that it's broken because the inner scroll view is in the wrong place.
This implies that the horizontal scroll happens wrongly in the blue area.

[image: Broken layout iOS 14.3]

Running exactly the same code **up to iOS 14.2** you get the correct layout .
[image: Correct Layout]

What do you think about this issue?
Am I missing something or it could be a UIKit bug?

Thanks

Comment: Any change in behavior from iOS 14.2 to 14.3 is worth reporting to Apple.

Comment: Hi matt,
we reported the issue to Apple a week ago, let's wait for an answer.
I'll keep the topic updated when I'll get any update.

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: We are running into the exact same issue. It seems to happen when `NSCollectionLayoutDimension`'s `estimatedHeight` is set to a value that is higher than the actual cell that is being rendered. When you set the `estimatedHeight` to the smallest size, it works as expected so upscaling seems to work but downscaling seems to cause the `_UICollectionViewOrthogonalScrollerEmbeddedScrollView` to get mispositioned. We're currently working around the issue by wrapping the `estimatedHeight` between `if #available(iOS 14.3, *) { ... } else { ... }`. Working on filing a `RADAR` as well.

Comment: Thanks for keeping up with this.

Comment: @drakon any update from Apple?

Comment: Hi everyone,
the Developer Technical Support answered us that the collection view team is aware of the bug and should release a fix in the next iOS versions.
Sadly, they didn't provide us an estimated release date for the fix.

Comment: Did a RADAR get filed for this? I'd like to monitor it if so please

Comment: I did file an issue with Apple, but it's still marked as Open and has not been groomed yet. I just checked Xcode 12.4 RC / iOS 14.4 RC and the issue is unfortunately still present.

Comment: I noticed the bug is still there on the official iOS 14.4 release. Still waiting for an answer by Apple...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me this problem is reproducible in iOS `14.3` and `14.4` . And now is fixed in `iOS 14.5 beta1`

Try to install the latest Xcode beta version `12.5 beta` and test it using a simulator running `iOS 14.5`

Xcode beta link: https://developer.apple.com/download/

Answer (score 12):

We have header with estimated height and some sections with `_UICollectionViewOrthogonalScrollerEmbeddedScrollView` were completely broken because of this regression. So here is a solution that worked in our case

```
public final class CollectionView: UICollectionView {
    
    public override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
    
        guard #available(iOS 14.3, *) else { return }
    
        subviews.forEach { subview in
            guard
                let scrollView = subview as? UIScrollView,
                let minY = scrollView.subviews.map(\.frame.origin.y).min(),
                minY > scrollView.frame.minY
            else { return }
    
            scrollView.contentInset.top = -minY
            scrollView.frame.origin.y = minY
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, this appears to workaround the issue well +1

Answer (score 6):

We have a slightly different use case where the section with the scroll view also uses estimated heights, so I modified `softenhard`'s solution to also adjust the height of the scrollview.

```
public final class CollectionView: UICollectionView {
    override public func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        guard #available(iOS 14.3, *) else { return }

        subviews.forEach { subview in
            guard
                let scrollView = subview as? UIScrollView,
                let minY = scrollView.subviews.map(\.frame.origin.y).min(),
                let maxHeight = scrollView.subviews.map(\.frame.height).max(),
                minY > scrollView.frame.minY || maxHeight > scrollView.frame.height
            else { return }

            scrollView.contentInset.top = -minY
            scrollView.frame.origin.y = minY
            scrollView.frame.size.height = maxHeight
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This one worked better for us too, originally looked like the previous one worked but due to the intermittent nature of the problem, it sometimes resulted in a shifted view.

Comment: thought that it fixed it better but we are still having issue, intermittently.

Comment: Please update the code to use ```guard #available(iOS 14.3, *) else { return }```  instead of  this code because its wrong ```if #available(iOS 14.3, *) { return }```

Comment: Thanks, @EhabSaifan. Updated.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue and the workarounds of the other answers didn't work for me.

So I made this extension to determine if it's the buggy iOS-Version:

```
extension UICollectionView {
    static var isIosVersionWithSizeEstimationBug: Bool {
        if #available(iOS 14.5, *) {
            return false
        }
        if #available(iOS 14.3, *) {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

And I use this to use an absolute height in this case. It might not be a workaround for every use case. But for me it's a stable solution:

```
let height: NSCollectionLayoutDimension = {
    let maxPossibleHeight: CGFloat = 280
    if UICollectionView.isIosVersionWithSizeEstimationBug {
        return .absolute(maxPossibleHeight)
    } else {
        return .estimated(maxPossibleHeight)
    }
}()
let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: height)
let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1/3), heightDimension: height)
let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(layoutSize: groupSize, subitem: item, count: 1)
let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
```